# UIPageViewController didFinishAnimating without user interaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

i have a problem i can't solve.

I need to call a method every time i move between pages in a UIPageViewController.

Recently found

```
-(void) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed{...
```

But this is only called if i swipe pages (gesture) or the second and subsequent times i switch to any page.

Is there a way to trigger an event every time i switch pages?.

Tried with inner ViewControllers (pages) viewDidLoad, but it's only called the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your code to the inner view controllers' `viewDidAppear`, which is called whenever these view controller are presented by the page view controller.